# What are some areas of C++ code that could be affected by porting to Visual 2005 and changing to unicode?

Tags: c++, unicode

We recently ported over legacy code to now use Visual Studio 2005 and unicode.

What are the key areas that are affected by switching to the unicode character set?

Comment: Um, string handling? What does your code do?

Comment: You ported legacy code to VS2005? Why bother? VS2005 is now legacy.

Comment: I'm simply the tester on this one and had no part in choosing what to port to. However, VS2005 is pretty stable and that's good for this particular thing because it is for downloading the correct msi installer for the application.

Comment: @Brian:  VS2008 is pretty stable, too, and that will work better on any OS Microsoft's put out for the last few years.  And, also, what are you porting from?  K&R C?  C with Classes?  C90?  Without knowing that, or what you're actually doing with characters or string, this is hard to answer.

Comment: This is a project that depends on another project that's in VS2005, so we want both of them be the same for now. Then in the future we will upgrade both of them at the same time.

Comment: Important discussion against using _T(""), wchar and TCHAR when porting to unicode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My biggest nightmare of all while starting to support unicode (I don't like the word 'converting to unicode') is 3rd-party libraries which accept char* for filenames, and then forward these to legacy windows APIs like CreateFileA.

It is very hard to make these support unicode if you don't have the library source code, and also, this practice is perfectly good on Linux where UTF-8 is universally supported.

What my team had to do is getting 8.3 filename for every file before feeding it into these APIs. It relies on registry setting (ON by default) that prevents windows from using non-ascii chars in 8.3 filenames, and in keeping 8.3 filenames in the first place.

This does not work if the broken library **creates** a file, because the 8.3 filename is not known before creation. We had to trick this by creating a wrapper which would create the file, allocate the 8.3 filename and then feed it to the library.

Comment: say what? that might be one of the most confusing few paragraphs I've read in a long time. what is an 8.3 filename?

Comment: 8.3 filename is something every file has under windows, as an additional name for the file. You can see them with "dir /x" command. For example, C:\Program files is also "C:\PROGRA~1" on my comp. It is important for supporting unicode in your applications, and for crating multi-platform software, because this is the only trick to do it right on windows, if you open files.

Comment: Lyrical remark: sorry for the confusion. I am amazed how doing text can be complicated sometimes. As all things, it should be handled the simplest possible way, but no simpler. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Answer (score 0):

MS changed the default setting in VS2005 for Treat WChar_t As Built in Type to "Yes" (Options/C-C++/Language).  This forced us to recompile/update all of the external libraries we were linking against.

Comment: Although that is just the default, you can turn the option off to retain compatibility with your legacy code.

Comment: Certainly! In in our case, it was just easier to recompile them. We knew we were going to continue to develop new solutions against them, and rather than turn it off in all newly developed solutions, we just decided to recompile the old. I was just trying to point out something to look out for.